# Browser could redirect to an url with POST?

Tags: php, javascript, http, browser

I was on a page that redirected me to my own web server (www.myserver.com) but the request was not a GET but a POST.

At first www.myserver.com couldn't process the request because I just had a route handler for handling "GET /". When I realized it could be a POST redirection (read about it on their guide) I created a route handler for "POST /" and the page was served.

Correct me if I'm wrong, so the browser COULD redirect to an url with POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES but the browser is supposed to prompt the user.  302 is not except allowed for GET and HEAD but 307 is allowed for POST.  From the HTTP RFC:

**307 Temporary Redirect**

> The requested resource resides
>   temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection MAY be altered
>   on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for
>   future requests. This response is only
>   cacheable if indicated by a
>   Cache-Control or Expires header field.
>
> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by
>   the Location field in the response.
>   Unless the request method was HEAD,
>   the entity of the response SHOULD
>   contain a short hypertext note with a
>   hyperlink to the new URI(s) , since
>   many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not
>   understand the 307 status. Therefore,
>   the note SHOULD contain the
>   information necessary for a user to
>   repeat the original request on the new
>   URI.
>
> If the 307 status code is received in
>   response to a request other than GET
>   or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT
>   automatically redirect the request
>   unless it can be confirmed by the
>   user, since this might change the
>   conditions under which the request was
>   issued.

What browser were you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page with a `<form>` tag which points to your page, then submit the form using Javascript when the page loads.

Comment: But I was not talking about forms, but POST redirections.